# apply a terminal conversion command to each file in a folder

Tags: finder, applescript, automator

How do you apply this terminal command `ffmpeg -i $f -ac 2 -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 48k -ar 24000 -write_xing 0 $f_converted;` to every file in a directory? ($f is the filename and $f_converted is the converted name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why **AppleScript** or **Automator** when this can be done in just **Terminal**? Are all the files in the same folder? What type of file is been converted, its extension, e.g **.mp4**?

If all the files are in the same folder and only the target files, then in **Terminal**, use to following commands:

```
cd /path/to/target_files
for f in *.*; do echo ffmpeg -i "$f" -ac 2 -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 48k -ar 24000 -write_xing 0 "${f%.*}"_converted"${f##*.}"; done
```

**Note:** The **for in do** *command* has an intentional `echo` *command* so as to run one time to see what the output of the formed command line will look like in order to see if it looks proper. Run it a second time without the `echo` *command* to do the actual processing. If the target file type is e.g. **.mp4**, you can change `*.*` to `*.mp4` or `*.[mM][pP]4`, where the latter handles both **.mp4** and **.MP4**.

If you are using e.g. **Automator** with some **Finder** *actions* to get the target files to then run this in a **Run Shell Script** *action*, then set **Pass input:** to **as arguments** and use the following for the *command*:

```
for f in "$@"
do
    ffmpeg -i "$f" -ac 2 -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 48k -ar 24000 -write_xing 0 "${f%.*}"_converted"${f##*.}"
done
```

---

- `"${f%.*}"` expands to just the filename portion, without the file extension.
- `"${f##*.}"` expands to just the extension portion, without the filename portion.

Comment: nice! did not know batch commands could be done in just terminal!